# vue vue-resource $http.get não reconhece json com [

Tags: php, vue.js

Tenho um php que entrega o seguinte conteúdo

```
[{"Id":"50630","Operador":"","Id_cadastro":"61693"}]
```

O vue-resource só reconhece se eu remover o []

meu código vue é

```
this.$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
     this.cervejarias = response.data.Id_cadastro;
}
```

No PHP estou fazendo assim:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data);
```

Estou esquecendo algo?

Este mesmo json, consigo ler pelo Angular.

Comment: Algo que você pode fazer também é trocar o seu código PHP por
`print json_encode($smtm->fetchAll());`

Comment: E para debugar códigos assim você pode usar `console.log(response)` e ver no seu console como os dados estão chegando.

Comment: Só vais queres mostrar um registo desse JSON? Não seria algo assim: http://jsfiddle.net/a312sa5a/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade correta de `response` é `body` e não `data`.

```
// supondo que o retorno seja [{"Id":"50630","Operador":"","Id_cadastro":"61693"}]
this.$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
  this.cervejarias = response.body[0].Id_cadastro;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou!!!
agora eu quero jogar isso tudo em um v-for
seria somente response.body;?

Comment: this.cervejarias = response.body

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou,  tudo belezinha agora.  Obrigado Amigos

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é evitar a escrita de Promises dessa forma, não só da margem para errar chaves como também tem uma leitura ruim.

Tente assim na próxima:

```
this.$http.get('data.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => this.cervejarias = res.Id_cadastro)
```

Repare que você tem o retorno chamando diretamente a chave da sua API. Caso precise trabalhar o retorno antes de fazer algo basta usar chaves na arrow function.

```
this.$http.get('data.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {

        // múltiplas linhas
        this.cervejarias = res.Id_cadastro)

    })
```